# XML deserializer namespace collision with legacy files

Tags: .net, xml, serialization

I am working in a legacy system in VB.NET. It stores data in local XML files, by using XMLSerializer and passing in an object. To read data it deserializes back to objects the same way.

We do not have explicit schemas or XML namespaces. I know this is far from ideal, and I know if we change the name or order of any properties then we break backward compatibility. But we are stuck with this basic system and a lot of existing files it must be able to read and write.

I have not touched any properties of the object being serialized. But I did start using System.Drawing.Point in another part of the application. Now when I attempt to serialize or deserialize, I get InvalidOperationException with this message:

> Types 'System.Windows.Point' and 'System.Drawing.Point' both use the
>   XML type name, 'Point', from namespace ''. Use XML attributes to
>   specify a unique XML name and/or namespace for the type.

I confess I don't understand how the system has suddenly decided this type is ambiguous. The property of the class throwing the error is declared specifically as System.Windows.Point. No instance of the other Point is serialized or deserialized, anywhere.

I have searched a great deal on this exception, but the discussion I see all appears to be related to web services and a class named by the developer. The answer seems to be either "rename your class," or "use XML attributes to specify new XML namespace for your type."

I think I cannot do either of those things. I cannot rename System.Windows.Point. I cannot change any tags the system expects to write or read, because I cannot break backward compatbility with any file written in the past.

How did this error start showing up, when I didn't do anything to change the XML? And how do I fix it without breaking my ability to access to a zillion existing XML files?

Edit: 
The XML file itself does not refer to "Point" anywhere. The XML looks like this:

```
<MyClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Segment>
        <ID>0</ID>
        <Location>
            <X>37</X>
            <Y>330</Y>
        </Location>
        (other properties)
    </Segment>
    <Segment>
    .....
</MyClass>
```

Comment: Can you provide a small code sample that demonstrates the issue? And/or a an xml file that has a Point in it?

Comment: Edited to provide a sample of the XML. I can't provide a small code sample that demonstrates the problem, because I don't know what part of this code is causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

It turns out that something written to XML did change. One small, rarely instantiated object had declared a member as "Point" without further specifying the type, and the compiler had defaulted to using System.Windows.Point. When I started referencing System.Drawing, that property silently changed so it was using Drawing.Point. (I don't know why the compiler did not start complaining this was an ambiguous type name.)

Anyway when the serializer tried to write a property of type Drawing.Point, after already having written a property of type Windows.Point, it realized the name collision and excepted.

The solution was to explicitly type both of the properties to the same thing.